# In Nativescript, is there a way wordwrap concatenated Labels?

Tags: label, nativescript

I am creating Labels dynamically from an array of strings so I have different colored and tap-able Labels  like this:

```
<Label *ngFor="let part of comment"
        [class.mention]="part.Mention" [class.hashtag]="part.Hashtag"
        (tap)="handleTap(part)" [text]="part.Text"></Label>
```

[Playground link](https://play.nativescript.org/?template=play-ng&id=lJm8ZT&v=3)

This works fine if all the Labels together are shorter than one line, but if they are longer than one line they will not wrap to the next line.  How can I get this to wordwrap?  Adding textWrap="true" does not work in this instance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use **WrapLayout** instead of stackLayout

```
<WrapLayout orientation="horizontal">
    <Label *ngFor="let part of comment" [class.mention]="part.Mention"
        [class.hashtag]="part.Hashtag" (tap)="handleTap(part)"
        [text]="part.Text"></Label>
</WrapLayout>
```

I just update Playground link
https://play.nativescript.org/?template=play-ng&id=lJm8ZT&v=6

Comment: That works great - Looks like I'll have to break my strings down to each individual word to avoid the odd spacing though.  Thank you!